# SQL Query too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a requirements to only select Clients who have had either NO transactions, or else, their last transaction was after a certain date.

At the moment, my query is taking too long.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT MAX(AC_CLOSEDDAT) FROM 
    Accs WHERE accs.AC_CLIENTCODE = c.CL_CLIENTCODE) AS LastTrans 
FROM Clients c 
WHERE CL_STATUS <> 'R' 
AND STORE_CODE = '69JX
```

I was hoping I could use a JOIN, but not sure.... I need Clients with no transactions, as well as ones with transactions within the last 2 years.

Using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a NOT EXISTS clause, which will give you the result for null transactions or no transaction after a given date, without needing any max.

```
SELECT * FROM Clients c
WHERE CL_STATUS <> 'R'
AND STORE_CODE = '69JX'
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT NULL FROM Accs a
    WHERE a.AC_CLIENTCODE = c.CL_CLIENTCODE
    AND a.AC_CLOSEDDAT > theDateToCompare)
```

Comment: This may work - but I'm not sure of two things: 1. Why 'SELECT NULL', as opposed to 'SELECT *'? And 2. Will this include Clients who have 0 lines in Accs?

Comment: @Craig 1. Because it's just a check of "existence", you don't wanna retrieve any row from the check. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use JOIN, just that it needs to be LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT c.*, MAX(AC_CLOSEDDAT) AS LastTrans
    FROM Clients c 
    LEFT JOIN Accs ON accs.AC_CLIENTCODE = c.CL_CLIENTCODE 
WHERE CL_STATUS <> 'R' 
    AND STORE_CODE = '69JX
```

Using LEFT JOIN will return all records from Clients no matter if there is a correspondent in the Accs table.

Answer (score 0):

With join, you can:

```
SELECT c.client_id
FROM Clients c 
LEFT JOIN  Accs a
  on (a.AC_CLIENTCODE = c.CL_CLIENTCODE AND 
      a.AC_CLOSEDDAT >= DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())
WHERE CL_STATUS <> 'R'
AND STORE_CODE = '69JX'
group by c.client_id;
```

but Raphaël Althaus's answer is best SQL, and the engine knows to execute it with hash join(eventualy).

Comment: This looks good too - but will it include clients with no Accs rows as well?

Comment: yes, you'll get all clients because is a `left join`, but if you add columns in the `select` clause, you need to add them also in the `group by` clause